# use global application states

Tags: apache-flex, states

I am trying to use global application states to manage roles in my application. How can I use `<properties.state>` everywhere in my application if I declare it in my top level application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  You shouldn't reference information defined in your main application file in the children of that file.

Comment: @Flextras, What if he were to inject the `state` property into the children via Mate or the like?

Comment: I think Flextras is right. There should be a better way to managing roles than with states. You can use mate to have a `user` object in which you can access for example a variable `isAdmin`.

Comment: @hering, I agree that there is probably a better solution out there than using states to manage roles in his application. My question had more to do with injecting properties into the children of the main application versus the children not being able to reference information in the main application. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I deduce that it is not possible to create global states.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create global states !!!